# How to apply master theorem of 2 binary search?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, master-theorem

In order to count occurences of a number in a sorted array, I'm using a binary search twice

The recurrence relation of a binary search is T(N/2)+1
by calling it twice, is it correct to say it's **2T(N/2) +2** ?

But using master theorem the result I'm getting is O(n) which is wrong

```
def NbOcc(T,v) :
bg=Bg(T,0,len(T)-1,v) // T(N/2) +1
bd=Bd(T,0,len(T)-1,v) // T(N/2) +1
if bg>bd :
    return 0
else :
    return bd-bg+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bg` and `Bd` functions are not a recursive call of `NbOcc` function. Hence, the time complexity of the `NbOcc` function is `T(n) = TBG(n-1) + TBD(n-1) + 1` such that `TBG` and `TBD` are time complexity of `Bg` and `Bd` functions respectively.

Now if both `Bg` and `Bd` functions are a binary search function, their time complexity will be in `O(log(n))`. Therefore, we can say `T(n)` is in `O(log(n))`.

In sum, you made a mistake in the recurrent formula as they are not a recursive call. Thus, you shouldn't have used the master theorem as it cannot be applied in your case (only applicable for analysis of the binary search inside each `Bg` and `Bd` functions depending on their implementations).